# How to find if today day of the month is greater then a particular date on the month with date-fns

Tags: javascript, date-fns

How can I find if todays date of the month is greater then 10 with date-fns

Basically I can get the first day of the month with `startOfMonth`
then add 10 days to that with `addDays` and then use ifAfter of `isBefore`.
The code could be looking like that:

```
greaterThan = 10;
today = new Date();
targetDate = addDays(startOfMonth(today), greaterThan);
isGreater = isAfter(today, targetDate);
```

Is there a shortcut withing date-fns to achieve in less code lines?

Comment: Q: Why not just use [Date.getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate): *The getDate() method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time.*

Comment: exacly, and this would work regardless of month

Answer (score 1):

```
var greaterThan10 = new Date().getDate() > 10;
```

Cause the (numerical) day of today will be greater (or not) in any other month as well? Or am I missing something?